# PHP imap_search KEYWORD documentation how to use

Tags: php, imap

I need to retrieve bounced email using a web app in PHP.

I need to find all emails return message starting from an email sent by the web app.

For example with an email sent (and saved into my DB with ID = 1): I want to show all message response linked to this email.

I tried using `imap_search` with options `SUBJECT "my original subject"` but it doesn't work all times! FOr example, gmail for bounced response, replace original subject into "`Delivery Status Notification (Failure)`"

So i'd like to do the search using others possible options. I see exist an option called `KEYWORD` but i don't find example and appropriate documentation how to use it.

I'd like to semplify my job for example inserting a unique indentifier into the header of my email sent, so I can search into INBOX responses using this identifier.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a little difficult. A few days' programming.

The kind of message you're looking at is called a DSN, or delivery status notification. It's not a response. It is related to the original message, but its relationship is a different kind, it's not a reply. (Forwarded messages are also not replies.)

You'll have to actually [parse the message/delivery-status part in DSN to find out](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464) which bounces relate to which messages. (It's even more difficult for forwarded messages, but perhaps you don't have that problem.)

The [keyword](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-51) keyword is for message flags, such as `\seen`.

Comment: Hi @arnt, so i can't use imap_search...is it true? My first approach was to save the message-ID of sent messages in database, then use imap_search with ALL filter, and search inside the body content if Message-ID is present... it works when the INBOX has not too emails. but with too email i run into timeout or memory excedeed error php. To reduce number of email to load, i can use SINCE and BEFORE filters, assuming SINCE >= date/time of sent message and BEFORE is arbitrary...+1 day I think is a good choise but not the rule (but I think DNS is immediate if appened?).

Comment: You can use SEARCH, but it will not deliver precise results. For example, if message A bounces and is a reply to message B, then a search for B's message-id will probably return the bounce that relates to message A.

Comment: Filter SEARCH doesn't work / not supported by gmail. I'm going to search for a better approach...

Comment: I use SEARCH with gmail, with good performance and no problems.

Comment: can you post a piece of example code of your imap_search call? I get error in SEARCH parameter

Comment: I have about 2000 lines of Java to generate IMAP search commands (my searches can be quite complicated). I'm afraid a *meaningful* small excerpt isn't possible.